# How can I programatically use the 'title' module to replace taxonomy title/description with fields?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a custom module which creates a taxonomy vocabulary and installs terms using  hook_install, is there a way that I can programatically replace the title and description properties with fields using the title module programatically during the installation process.